# Is There Have Solution To Load Video In Android? I Try To Load But Give Message Can't Play Video

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following error:

> Can't play this video.

as you can see in the image below:

[image]

LoginAppActivity.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_app);

    emailInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bgVideo);
    String videoPath = "android:resource//"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bg3;
    String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.start();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

this for activity login app xml
activity_login_app.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/bgVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: does it play when using `videoPath` but not `vidAddress`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agreed that in VdeoView we can not see all videos and I get an error

> Can't play this video

So, I have alternative ways. These are steps to load video:

**Step 1**

Add this dependency in app level `build.gradle`:

```
// Exo-Player
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.15.0'
```

**Step 2**

Add this view to your activity/fragment `.xml` file:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A6000000" />
```

**Step 3**

Add this code in your `.java` file to load/show video:

```
// Declare variables
private PlayerView playerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;

// Initialize variable
playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector =
            new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

 player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

// Set player and play video
playerView.setPlayer(player);
MediaSource mVideoSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUri)); // videoUri is URL.
player.prepare(mVideoSource); // set ready
player.setPlayWhenReady(true); // set true to play when our player is reay to use.
```

Add below method in the same file:

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri mUri) {
    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)), bandwidthMeter);
    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

I hope it will work like a charm.